# Reading in a file and processing data

Tags: java

I am a noobie at programming and I can't seem to figure out what to do.

I am to write a Java program that reads in any number of lines from a file and generate a report with:

the count of the number of values read
the total sum
the average score (to 2 decimal places)
the maximum value along with the corresponding name.
the minimum value along with the corresponding name.

The input file looks like this:

```
55527    levaaj01   
57508    levaaj02   
58537    schrsd01   
59552    waterj01   
60552    boersm01   
61552    kercvj01   
62552    buttkp02   
64552    duncdj01   
65552    beingm01
```

I program runs fine, but when I add in 
    **score = input.nextInt();** and
    **player = input.next();**
The program stops working and the keyboard input seems to stop working for the filename.
I am trying to read each line with the int and name separately so that I can process the data and complete my assignment. I don't really know what to do next.

**Here is my code:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program1 {

private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
private static int fileRead = 0;
private String fileName = "";
private int count = 0;
private int score = 0;
private String player = "";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Program1 p1 = new Program1();

    p1.getFirstDecision();

    p1.readIn();

}  

public void getFirstDecision() { //*************************************

    System.out.println("What is the name of the input file?");

    fileName = input.nextLine(); // gcgc_dat.txt

}



public void readIn(){           //*********************************************

    try {

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName + ".txt");
        fileRead = 1;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 

        String str;

        int line = 0;

        while((str = br.readLine()) != null){

           score = input.nextInt();
           player = input.next();

           System.out.println(str);  

           line++;
           score = score + score;
           count++;

        }

       System.out.println(count);
       System.out.println(score);             

       br.close();

    }

    catch (Exception ex){

       System.out.println("There is no shop named: " + fileName);         

    }    

  } 

}
```

Comment: To compare strings you need to use .equals() not ==.

Comment: I think your assignment is steering you towards putting the data you read into a list- or dictionary-like structure to perform the reporting on - create the aggregates (sum + avg) and sort ascending and descending (min + max).

Comment: @DavidPostill on top. the code is very confusing. the op using BufferReader to read this file but use scanner to read variables?!!!!

Comment: @xerias91 I post my answer lemme know how much I helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you used `BufferReader` with `Scanner` is totally **wrong** .

**Note**: you can use `BufferReader` in Scanner constructor.

For example :

```
try( Scanner input = new Scanner( new BufferedReader(new FileReader("your file path goes here")))){

 }catch(IOException e){
 }
```

**Note**: your file reading process or other processes must be in `try` block because in catch `block` you cannot do anything because your connection is closed. It is called [try catch block with resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

**Note**:

> A BufferedReader will create a buffer. This should result in faster
>   reading from the file. Why? Because the buffer gets filled with the
>   contents of the file. So, you put a bigger chunk of the file in RAM
>   (if you are dealing with small files, the buffer can contain the whole
>   file). Now if the Scanner wants to read two bytes, it can read two
>   bytes from the buffer, instead of having to ask for two bytes to the
>   hard drive.
>
> Generally speaking, it is much faster to read 10 times 4096 bytes
>   instead of 4096 times 10 bytes.

Source [BufferedReader in Scanner's constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744943/bufferedreader-in-scanners-constructor)

**Suggestion**: you can just read each line of your file by using `BufferReader` and do your parsing by yourself, or you can use `Scanner` class that gives you ability to do parsing tokens.

[difference between Scanner and BufferReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231369/scanner-vs-bufferedreader)

As a hint you can use this sample for your parsing goal

Code:

```
        String input = "Kick 20";
        String[] inputSplited = input.split(" ");
        System.out.println("My splited name is " + inputSplited[0]);
        System.out.println("Next year I am " + (Integer.parseInt(inputSplited[1])+1));
```

Output:

```
My splited name is Kick
Next year I am 21
```

**Hope you can fixed your program by given hints.**